# How to paginate response from function based view of django rest framework?

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have written a code snippet like below, i need to achieve pagination in this, kindly let me know how is it possible. Also due to some reasons i want to use only function based views.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def PersonView(request):
    context={'request': request}
    person_objects = Person.objects.all()
    if len(person_objects) > 0:
        person_data = PersonSerializer(person_objects, many=True, context=context)
        return Response(person_data.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Why does it need to be a function view? can't you just make it a `ListView`?..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

@api_view(['GET',])

@permission_classes([AllowAny,])

def PersonView(request):

    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = 10
    person_objects = Person.objects.all()
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(person_objects, request)
    serializer = PersonSerializer(result_page, many=True)
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: It works for me, however context is not used, so I think you should ignore it.

Comment: what if you want to get a specify page that it comes from a request GET param?

Comment: How do i paginate data that does not need to be serialized? i.e the data is already in json format. I have tried passing the json data into the 'paginator.get_paginated_response' method but i get an error saying missing positional argument 'data'.

Answer (score 6):

You can also define custom pagination class by overriding PageNumberPagination

pagination.py

```
from rest_framework import pagination
class StandardResultsSetPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_query_param = 'page'
    page_size_query_param = 'per_page'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

it will help to define

> page_size, page query custom parameters and max_page_size

views.py

```
from rest_api.pagination import StandardResultsSetPagination

@api_view(['GET',])
@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
def PersonView(request):
    person_objects = Person.objects.all()
    if len(person_objects)> 0:
        paginator = StandardResultsSetPagination()
        result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(person_objects, request)
        serializer = PersonSerializer(result_page, many=True)
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response({},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Eg:**
**Request**

```
GET https://api.example.org/persons/?page=1&per_page=10
```

**Response**

```
HTTP 200 OK
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/persons/?page=2&per_page=10",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## The ACCEPTED answer has a BUG

A ModelSerializer accepts a queryset or an object, in the accepted answer the `PersonSerializer` is given the ouput of `paginator.paginate_queryset` which returns a [list](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L216) containing single element of class [Page](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/paginator.py#L166) and thus the serializer will either return incomplete data or no data at all(know this because have tried and seen wrong results).

This can be easily fixed by passing the actual queryset to the serializer which in this case will be `person_objects`,

So the final code will be,

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

@api_view(['GET',])
@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
def PersonView(request):
    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = 10
    person_objects = Person.objects.all()
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(person_objects, request)
    serializer = PersonSerializer(person_objects, many=True)  # MAIN CHANGE IS HERE
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

This fixes the bug but passing the complete queryset to serializer will take lot of time for serializing since serializer works on lazy approach, but this performance issue is in itself a new question.